# Redirect standard output isn't flushed during process execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process, redirectstandardoutput

I have a console application and I want to process the std out in a c# application.

Basically I already managed to do this with this code:

```
Process ProcessObj = new Process();

ProcessObj.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingPath;
ProcessObj.StartInfo.FileName = ApplicationPath;
ProcessObj.StartInfo.Arguments = ApplicationArguments;

ProcessObj.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessObj.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

ProcessObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

// Start the process
ProcessObj.Start();

// loop through until the job is done
bool stopper = false;
while (!stopper)
{
    stopper = ProcessObj.WaitForExit(100);

    string line = null;

    // handle normal outputs (loop through the lines)
    while (true)
    {
        line = ProcessObj.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;

        Logger.Trace("Out: \"" + line + "\"");
    }
}
```

When the process runs only a few seconds it looks like the whole thing is working without any problem. When I change the configuration of the console application to calculate more, it comes that the process is running for hours. In this time my C# application gets no response from the console app. Since the console app is hidden it looks like the app stucked but that's not true. It is already running in the background and it seems that all std outputs are only piped through to my c# app when the console app was finished the execution.
So the problem is, I don't see the std out lines live in my c# app. It will be refreshed after hours when the console app has finished.

Is there any way to flush this std out redirection?
Anybody knows why this isn't working like I want?

PS: When I execute the console app as standalone in a normal cmd window the outputs are shown live without any problem.

Please help.

Comment: You should be using only `ProcessObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` as Error Redirection is not used by you in the code!

Comment: ok... that's just a code fragment so you'd have the same while(true) loop for error also in the real code.

Comment: i would tell you to use `ProcessObj.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;`. I had a similar problem sometime before and when I replaced the redirections it was solved.

Comment: You can use Process.BeginOutputReadLine but that only fixing buffering on your side.  Many programs written in C or C++ also buffer the stdout and stderr streams themselves.  Fixing that requires their source code so that you can put fflush calls in strategic places.

Comment: That's interesting Hans Passant, thx. I mentioned that the commandline app itself is printing the outputs in realtime to the black windows console when executing it standalone. Does this mean that the problem is with my gui app? Even with the "Process.BeginOutputReadLine" the gui app isn't realtime and just refreshes the output when the console app was stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Try and read the output while the application is running? And save it to a buffer? Then process the output when the application exits.

pseudo stuff

```
string buffer = string.Empty;
while(!process.HasExited)
{
    string line = process.Stream.ReadLine();
    if (line != null)
        buffer += Enviorment.Newline + line
}

// Do stuff without put here
Console.Write(buffer);
```

Comment: I've done something similar. See my initial post. I'm reading every 100ms the Stream but there is nothing in it until the console app was stopped.